# (Pandas) Working with monthly data where some months are missing

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to calculate sales forecasts using the last 12 months worth of data for each of the products I sell.

I have time series data with a product name, a month, and a number of purchases in that month. However, some months where there were no sales, there is no data for that month.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
2014-06  product1  100
2014-07  product1  50
2014-10  product1  120
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
2014-06  product1  100
2014-07  product1  50
2014-08  product1  
2014-09  product1  
2014-10  product1  120
```

with a row for every month, not just the months with data. What's the most effective way to add the rows where the given month has no sales data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Dataframe.reindex` after constructing a new `PeriodIndex` with the missing months, using `pd.date_range` and `to_period()`. First, I'll recreate your data, converting your months to instances of `Period`:

```
index = pd.to_datetime(['2014-06', '2014-07', '2014-10']).to_period('M')
data = pd.DataFrame({
        'name': 'product1',
        'count': [100, 50, 120]
    }, index=index)
```

Now we create a new index with all of the months in the range:

```
new_index = pd.date_range(
    start=index[0].to_timestamp(how='end'),
    end=index[-1].to_timestamp(how='end'),
    freq='M').to_period()
```

This looks like:

```
>>> new_index
PeriodIndex(['2014-06', '2014-07', '2014-08', '2014-09', '2014-10'],
            dtype='int64', freq='M')
```

Such that:

```
>>> res = data.reindex(new_index, method='backfill')
>>> res

         count      name
2014-06    100  product1
2014-07     50  product1
2014-08    120  product1
2014-09    120  product1
2014-10    120  product1
```

You'll notice that both the `name` and `count` have been backfilled, whereas you only wanted the `name` to be backfilled. We can set the `count` for the new rows to be `NaN` as follows:

```
ix = new_index.difference(index)
res.loc[ix, 'count'] = None
```

So that:

```
>>> res

         count      name
2014-06    100  product1
2014-07     50  product1
2014-08    NaN  product1
2014-09    NaN  product1
2014-10    120  product1
```